# What is a fair game?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability, martingales

Suppose $X_n$ is the fortune of a gambler after $n$ th game. Then the game is called fair (Breiman 1968) if

$$E[X_{n+1} \mid X_1, \dots, X_n] = X_n \forall n$$

My question is why a fair game is not defined as the following

$$E[X_{n+1}] = E[X_n] \forall n$$ i.e. $$E[X_{n+1}- X_n]=0$$. This should be the proper definition as a fair game is where avg. gain is zero. Nothing conditioning should be there.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: I want to know why in the definition of martingale (which is a model of a fair game) conditioning is used ? E[tomorrow's fortune | past] = today's fortune. Why is it not E[tomorrow's fortune]= E[today's fortune] ?

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: thats what i asked. If you had noticed "carefully" then 1) stands for the conditional expectation and 2) expectation. I thought that was obvious.

Comment: @RossMillikan: I have modified the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\operatorname{E}[X_{n+1}\mid X_1,X_2,\ldots, X_n] = X_n\;, \forall n$$

That's an ... interesting definition.  It says the game's odds can be *adjusted* given knowledge of the gambler's past fortune, but will be considered fair if that adjustment *always* means that the gambler's fortune can be expected not to change after each game (whatever it may be at the time).

Of course, since $\operatorname{E}[Y] = \operatorname{E}\!\left[\operatorname{E}[Y\mid X]\right]$ then the familiar definition follows:

$$\begin{align}\operatorname{E}[X_{n+1}] & = \operatorname{E}\left[\operatorname{E}[X_{n+1}\mid X_1,X_2,\ldots, X_n]\right] \\ & = \operatorname{E}[X_{n}]\;, \forall n \end{align}$$

Which is an equivalent, but somewhat weaker, statement that a game is fair if the gambler's *expected* fortune does not depend on how many games are played.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted this kind of explanation.

Answer (score 2):

A definition of a fair game is one where the expectation value is zero, so people who like risk would always play it.

Playing heads or tails with a fair coin with a friend under the rules that the cost for the game is 1 dollar and the winner gets $2$ dollars. Lottery, for example isn't a fair game, since the probability you win multiplied by the prize is smaller than the cost of the ticket.

Comment: Oops, I need some coffee.

Comment: I'm drinking mine right now :)

Comment: @Bananarama: The above answer is wrong. Suprising upvotes !!!

Comment: @user148951 I'm sorry, but the question has been modified significantly since I answered, and it wasn't clear what you were asking at the beginning, also consider editing your title.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the reason lies how to compare two dependent (in random sense) entities. Suppose today's fortune is $Y$ and tomorrow's is $X$. Then a fair game should be $E[X|Y ] = Y$ a.e. i.e. we fix a $Y=y$ and then calculate the expectation of $X$. So, we remove the randomness of $Y$ in this way. In some sense, it is a way to make both the fortunes independent.

If we take the unconditional average then tomorrow's expected fortune will contain the randomness of today's. In some sense, this is not a fair comparison.

This argument is not much technical. Please comment so that I can evaluate my understanding.