# Is the game with given conditions fair?

Tags: probability

A gambler rolls two unbiased dice and stands to loss of $ \$2$ if he fails to throw a six, to win $ \$4$ if he throws one six and to win $ \$10$ if he throws two sixes. Is the game fair?

I can find probability for all three cases but to decide whether game is fair or not? Could someone help me with this?

Comment: have a look at this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/839628/what-is-a-fair-game

Comment: Do you know that a game is considered fair if the expected change of wealth on each play is zero?  What is the expected change of wealth for this game?

Comment: Expect to win ...
$$10(\frac 1{36})+4(\frac{10}{36})-2 (\frac {25}{36})
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fairness of a game is determined by the expected win amount, which is the returns expected if the game is played a lot of times and the results averaged.

$$E(X) = \frac{\sum \text{results}}{\text{number of games played}}$$

This is equivalent to:

$$E(X)=\sum_\limits{i=1}^N x_i P(X=x_i)$$

The probabilities for each event are read as:

> The probability that the payout is $-\$2$ is $\frac{25}{36}$
>
> The probability that the payout is $\$4$ is $\frac{10}{36}$ (assuming $1$ six means EXACTLY $1$ six).
>
> The probability that the payout is $\$10$ is $\frac{1}{36}$

Putting these into the formula gives:

$$E(X) = -2\frac{25}{36} + 4\frac{10}{36} + 10\frac{1}{36}$$

$$=\frac{-50+40+10}{36}$$

$$=0$$

This means the expected payout is zero, and so no-one wins, and hence the game is fair.